# range.clear({contentsOnly:false}) Does Not Work As Expected in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

This code does not clear anything. is it a bug? If so, where to report it?

```
function clearTheRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1);
  range.setBackground("yellow");
  range.setValue("test");
  range.clear({contentsOnly:false});
}
```

`range.clear()` works as expected though.

Here is the link to sheet where i test it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H79hEr2KhVGV4xTICRgLa_bPfimAV1gFXir6Ht_YouA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clear` will only "consider" the things passed in the options parameter.
In your case it looks at the options, sees it should look at contents but not clear them.  Everything not supplied is assumed to be `false` and will *not* be cleaned.
The only part of the field names are a bit of a misnomer, it's just that people usually only want to clear one thing rather than everything except something.

Try `range.clear({formatOnly: true});` to clear the formatting or `range.clear({contentsOnly: true});` to clear the content.

Comment: in that case you just provide `range.clear({contentsOnly: true});`

Comment: yes, that works. But then, if i want to use a variable there instead of true or false constant -  i can't. If i want to clear everything, including format, then i need to invoke the clear() without parameters.

like this:

```
function clearTheRange(contentsOnly) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1);
  range.setBackground("yellow");
  range.setValue("test");
  range.clear({contentsOnly:contentsOnly});
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, please consider accepting the answer if this helped you. Thanks

Comment: yes, i will accept your answer, as you are completely right with it. It just breaks my logic - if i  say `range.clear({formatOnly: false})`, it shoud behave same as `range.clear()`

Comment: I agree, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear(Object)) is not very clear about it either. You have to imagine the options object as initialised with everything set to false. Alternatively you can use `clearContent()`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i came with the following solution if i need to use variable for contentsOnly:

```
function test() {
  clearTheRange(false);
}

function clearTheRange(contentsOnly) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1);
  range.setBackground("yellow");
  range.setValue("test");
  //range.clear({contentsOnly:contentsOnly}); - this will not work if contentsOnly is false;
  if (contentsOnly) range.clearContent(); else range.clear();
}
```